# How to split a list into two using even and odd positions?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to split a list into even and odd based on their index/position in the list. For example for the list `[2,3,6]` the result should be `even = [2,6]` and `odd = [3]`.

I want to use the approach that doesn't use list comprehensions -- matching on two elements at a time and  putting one the evens list and one in the odds list.

But I am unsure of the syntax to get it working. I know how to logically but I am struggling with syntax. Here is what I have so far:

```
splitOnPos :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
splitOnPos [] = ([], [])
splitOnPos (x1:x2:xs) = (odds, evens)   
    where 
        odds  = x1 : splitOnPos xs
        evens = x2 : splitOnPos xs
```

I get the following errors about types:

```
* Couldn't match expected type `[a]' with actual type `([a], [a])'
    * In the second argument of `(:)', namely `splitOnPos xs'
      In the expression: x2 : splitOnPos xs
      In an equation for `evens': evens = x2 : splitOnPos xs
```

Comment: @MichaelLitchard i have just editted it with the error it is to do with the types and happening because i cant figure out syntax

Comment: @httpsissecure, you haven't given a [repro].

Comment: @Enlico i did i said for example if we had list [2,3,6] even = [2,6] odd = [3]

Comment: @httpsissecure, apparently you haven't read the link I've posted.

Comment: @Enlico that is all the code there is from it only 5 or so lines i basically want to split the list based on even and odd positions, using the method i stated above in the question but i am unsure how to with lack of knowledge with haskell syntax

Comment: @httpsissecure, _all the code there is from it only 5 or so lines_? Great, what is `split`? There's no such a thing in the `Prelude`, where do you take it from?

Comment: @httpsissecure I recommend giving every value an explicit type, it will lead you to the solution. Do this, instead of getting someone to find the problem for you, and you will come away with a stronger understanding.

Comment: @Enlico split is the function i am trying to write to do as i have stated above but i cant seem to get the syntax right with the type error

Comment: @httpsissecure, `splitOnPos` or `split`? Make up you mind and improve your low quality question to an acceptable level.

Comment: @MichaelLitchard i know how to write it for explicit types but i am trying to better my knowledge by allowing it to work for generic types and just need a little help

Comment: @Enlico your right i will edit the question right now i realised my mistake

Comment: @Enlico does the code make more sense now i am trying to create the function that splits into 2 lists one with even positions and one with odd positions using this method matching on two elements at a time and putting one the evens list and one in the odds list. but i am a bit unsure about how to write the code for the inductive case

Comment: Good, now the code example is moderately less unreadable. As regards to what's wrong with the code, the compiler is telling you pretty much all you need. Now do as MichaelLitchard suggested and you'll see.

Comment: @Enlico i have already wrote it for explicit types i am trying now to write it for the generic types and can't seem to and i was just needing some help thats why i came here ive been stuck at this for a while now nothing seems to spring to my mind

Comment: @httpsissecure there is **_no way_** that code can work if you put "explicit types" in it. So whatever you've done with "explicit types" does not correspond to the code you've shown.

Comment: @Enlico nevermind i wrote for another function but i wouldn't even know how to write this for explicit types either i am completely lost in the 2nd case

Comment: breaking edits are forbidden on SO. you might want to hide it from searches by your teacher, but it's not allowed to make edits which invalidate the answers or make the question unclear and unreadable. further such actions will be flagged for moderator intervention.

Answer (score 4):

You were almost there. It should have been

```
splitOnPos :: [a] -> ([a], [a])
splitOnPos [] = ([], [])
splitOnPos (x1:x2:xs) = (x1:odds, x2:evens)   
    where 
        (odds, evens) = splitOnPos xs
```

As the error message reminds you, the function returns a *tuple* (a pair) of lists, not just one list to which you could cons (`:`) anything.

So we take the tuple in, and prepend each of the two head elements to the corresponding list, repackaging the result as a pair again, so the type fits:

```
 ( x1:odds        <--       ( odds
   ,                          ,           <---- recursive call
   x2:evens )     <--         evens )
```

You have one more equation to write here, so that all cases are covered. Right now you only handle the empty list case, and the lists with two elements or more.

The singleton list case isn't handled. As the result it will only work for lists with even length:

```
> splitOnPos [0..9]
([0,2,4,6,8],[1,3,5,7,9])

> splitOnPos [0..10]
([0,2,4,6,8*** Exception: <interactive>:(574,1)-(577,37):
 Non-exhaustive patterns in function splitOnPos
```

Comment: There's a really cool trick for this specific problem, too, that lets you pattern match on one element at a time instead of two. (It also means it will work for one-element lists instead of crashing as this one does.) `splitOnPos (x:xs) = (x:evens, odds) where (odds, evens) = splitOnPos xs`

Comment: @DanielWagner that's a nice oldie _and_ goodie, even extendable to triples etc., but OP wanted to understand _their_ code and how to fix it so I was focusing on _that_. :)

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the code by adding a case where the list only contains one elemt. This should not give any exeptions. Basically it goes sending x and y to the different lists. x being the first elem will always going to be odd, while y being the second, even.

```
splitOE :: [Int] -> ([Int],[Int])
splitOE []       = ([],[])
splitOE [x]      = ([x],[])
splitOE (x:y:xs) = (x:odds, y:evens)   
    where 
        (odds, evens) = splitOE xs
```